# Trouble with my PHP validation script

Tags: php

So I have created a PHP validation script. On test I filled and submitted the forms but so far $error returns undefined index and no data is set into the database. Can anyone take a look and give a second opinion on why its not functioning as intended? To my eye it all looks OK.

Otherwise my script runs OK (Insert into DB) it's just something about my validation script breaks it.

```
 <?php  

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {  

        if ($_POST['name'] != "") {  
            $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
            if ($_POST['name'] == "") {  
                $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/><br/>';  
            }  
        } else {  
            $errors .= 'Please enter a name.<br/>';  
        }  

           if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {  

        if ($_POST['address'] != "") {  
            $_POST['address'] = filter_var($_POST['address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
            if ($_POST['address'] == "") {  
                $errors .= 'Please enter a valid address<br/><br/>';  
            }  
        } else {  
            $errors .= 'Please enter a address.<br/>';  
        }  

           if (isset($_POST['postcode'])) {  

        if ($_POST['postcode'] != "") {  
            $_POST['postcode'] = filter_var($_POST['postcode'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
            if ($_POST['postcode'] == "") {  
                $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/><br/>';  
            }  
        } else {  
            $errors .= 'Please enter a name.<br/>';  
        }  

        if (!$errors) {  



$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$photo = $_POST['photo'];
$db1 = new dbmember();
$db1->openDB();
$numofrows = $db1->insert_member('', $name, $address, $postcode, $photo);
echo "Success. Number of rows affected:
<strong>{$numofrows}<strong>";



$sql="SELECT * from member";
$result=$db1->getResult($sql);
echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
echo "<tr><th>Member ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Photo</th></tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>{$row['mid']}</td><td>{$row['name']}</td>";
 echo "<td>{$row['address']}";
echo "<td>{$row['postcode']}";
 echo"<td><img height='80' width='120' src='{$row['photo'] }' /></td>";  
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";


$db1->closeDB();
}


        }
        }
        }
            echo "Records updated!<br/><br/>";  
        } else {  
            echo '<div style="color: red">' . $errors . '<br/></div>';  
        }  

?>  

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="myform" class = "well" id="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm(  );">

Please fill in the fields to add a new member
<p></p>
<input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Enter member name"name="name" id="name" /><br />
<input type="text" class="span3"placeholder="Enter an address"name="address" id="address" /><br />
<input type="text" class="span3"placeholder="Enter a postcode"name="postcode" id="postcode" /><br />
<input type="text"class="span3" placeholder="Enter a picture (optional)"name="photo" /><br />
<p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" >Submit  </button>
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: Dude. Please add the concrete error message and highlight the line it is occured at.

Comment: 81 lines of code - can you narrow it down a little?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on the affected area(s), then show us the results.

Comment: It's here towards the end where $error is `echo '<div style="color: red">' . $errors . '<br/></div>';` However I'm not too worried about an empty variable, just curious to see why the conditions are not being checked and the DB isn't getting updated. Anyone?

Comment: @user2627262 And the error msg? - You're never defining $errors. You're using it without any existence. Additionally you should improve code formatting. It's unreadable. I can't distinguish between the differen conditional blocks.

Comment: @user2627262 Try this `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` instead of `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>`. You have a missing semi-colon, could be the fault. Try that and let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: @user2627262 So, any luck? (with my suggestion/comment)

Comment: @fred I'll have to read up on the usage of vardump. However, I do know $error is empty for the time being (null) but thanks.

Comment: @user2627262 You're welcome. Have you tried my suggestion about your missing semi-colon? And here is the link to PHP var_dump http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: I'll double check but I think I'm OK on the semi, netbeans usaully flags up syntax issues

Answer (score 1):

Your button doesn't have a `name="Submit"` attribute. Your php code can't find the `$_POST['Submit']` because it doesn't exist.

Consequently, the `if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {` condition will return false meaning the validation is never performed and the $error variable never set to a value.

Comment: Hm, not entirely sure about that. The OP's code contains `onsubmit="return validateForm(  );` so that could work and take that as `submit` validation. However, I'm not 100% certain about that, but it does make sense. **Your answer also makes sense.**

Comment: @Dolchio Good suggestion, but I'm still not having any joy with the script. Any other hints? I tried this as well `: value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];` on each field.